# Passing values(array) from a checkbox in a php page to another php page using jinput

Tags: php, arrays, joomla

I am trying to retrieve the value of checkboxes when selected in a form. I have used the following method to store all the check boxes in an array; using [] after the input name:

`<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="documents[]" value="<?php echo $this->user->construction; ?>" />Construction of building<br/>`

And then I store the selected values right after, on submit:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){//to run PHP script on submit
                                    if(!empty($_POST['documents'])){
                                    // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
                                    foreach($_POST['documents'] as $selected){
                                    echo $selected."</br>";
                                    }
                                    }
                                    }
```

On the other php page, I try to retrieve the value of the selected checkboxes in the variable call "documents":

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$documents = $app->input->getVar('documents',array());
```

But after retrieving the data, the only value returned is = Array.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to get this done on my own:

```
   $docs = $_POST['documents'];
        foreach ($docs as $documents)
{
        $msg .= "$documents\n"  ;

}
```

Then I used the variable, $msg to hold the values of the checkbox in the array.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve a JForm post data using Jinput, you can use

```
$jinput   = JFactory::getApplication()->input;

$formData = new JRegistry($jinput->get('jform', '', 'array'));

$documents= $formData->get('documents','');
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have tried that, but now I get an empty array. It seems the data is not being posted from the form? Have I posted from the form correctly?

Comment: Can you tellme which php page you are talking about. Does this page belong to a module component and which page of component if its a component?

Comment: Yes it belongs to a component. The component is called BT property. I am posting the data straight to email. So, I am trying to post the value of the array from the apply for property page (contact agent) to be stores in the agent controller page, and then to an email address on submit. I can get every other textbox input. Just the array (checkbox input) is a problem.